# What is the difference between androidx.navigation:navigation-ui & android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx?

Tags: android, android-navigation

What is the difference between androidx.navigation:navigation-ui & android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx ?

When i am using android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx dependency in my gradle, i am able to use #navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController).

However, when i use androidx.navigation:navigation-ui and use the same code, the setupWithNavController method is red and hence cannot be found anymore...

Can someone help ?

Comment: The latter is from the new architecture components introduced in Jetpack, which explains the reason why you can access navControllers.

Comment: However, on the official page of Android, it shows this one ndroidx.navigation:navigation-ui  with a new version of 2.1.0. when i try to put this version on the dependency i am using in my app (android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx), it says this version is not available...

Comment: One is from the new `android` support library and the other is from a separate architecture navigation library. Just the way there are Fragments from the support library and also from the framework. When you add the arch one, you get these classes support: [Arch classes summary](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/package-summary#classes)

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Navigation component documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#pre-androidx_dependencies_2), the `android.arch` syntax is a Pre-AndroidX dependency.